# Set UIImageView's alpha in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to set the alpha of a UIImageView in a different class. In Class1.h I have a UIImageView that needs to change in Class2.m in IBAction. The alpha of the UIImageView initially is 1. This is my code that does not work despite not having errors.

```
Class1.h
{
IBOutlet UIImageView *Livello2Image;
}
-(void)setAlpha:(int)a;

Class1.m
- (void)setAlpha:(int)a
{
Livello2Image.alpha = a;
}

Class2.m
-(IBAction)ALP{
Class1 *class = [[Class1 alloc]init];
[class setAlpha: 0];}
```

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: Livello2Button is an outlet -- is it non-nil when you are calling setAlpha?

Comment: The alpha of the Livello2Button initially is 1. @BenFlynn

Comment: So if you inspect the value Livello2Button of Livello2Button in your setAlpha method it is non-nil? I presume your class is a ViewController an you are loading Livello2Button from a xib? If the view hasn't loaded when you call this, alpha won't get set. Also, you say you want to set the alpha of a UIImageView and your code has a UIButton. Maybe you could clear up your question and add more detail.

Comment: You're right, now I correct the question. @BenFlynn

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what you mean when you say it "does not work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Class2` when you do

> Class1 *class = [[Class1 alloc]init];

That creates a new instance of `Class1` and then you set its alpha (then this new instance is destroyed or leaked depending on your ARC setting). This isn't what you want because you already have an existing instance of `Class1` that you should be changing. That means you need a reference (pointer) to the instance.

When you create your `Class2` instance, you should give it a reference to the `Class1` instance. `Class2` should have a property in which to store the reference.

---

So in your `ViewController` class you should implement `prepareForSegue:sender:`. This will give you the new instance of `ProvaViewController` (via `segue.destinationViewController`). You need to add the property to `ProvaViewController` (`@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;`) and then use that property to change the alpha (`[self.viewController Trasparenza:0];`).

Though... Your 'go back' button does seem to push a new view controller modally rather than actually go back (dismiss the current view as it is also presented modally). So really you need to think about your view controller structure as it's a bit mad currently...

---

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:...]) {
        [(ProvaViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setViewController:self];
    }
}
```

Read the guide [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CustomizingDetailView/CustomizingDetailView.html), particularly the section "Send Data to the Detail Scene".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, what should change in the code? I'm a beginner.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. This is my project: [link](http://rapidshare.com/files/29109553/AndreaPicchi.zip). @Wain

Comment: Can you give me an example of 'prepareForSegue:sender:' and 'segue.destinationViewController'? Thanks :) @Wain

Comment: Hello, I tried to implement the code but it did not work. Can you send me my project "AndreaPicchi.zip" with the changes already made? Thanks again :) @Wain

Comment: Did you change the way your view controllers are presented so you actually go back rather than always presenting new ones? And did you read the guide I linked?

Comment: Yes, I have changed the button "Go back" in the Storyboard (Is that right?) and yes, I read the guide.

Comment: I should hope not. You added the property to `ProvaViewController`? And set it in `prepareForSegue`? And debugged the 'go back' button action? And it goes back and you can see that the property have a reference to `ViewController`?

Comment: Yes, I have added the property in ProvaViewController ("ViewController *property" in ProvaViewController.h is correct?) and I have followed the guide to set it in prepareForSegue. But in what sense "you can see that the property have a reference to ViewController"?

Comment: Debugging. If you set a breakpoint on a line of code that's executed when the tap the back button the app will be stopped and you can examine its state. This allows you to check that you're in the correct place. It should also allow you to check that the view controller instance is the correct one.

Comment: The application works and does not stop (so I did not put any breakpoint, right?) but the alpha does not change.

Comment: Put the breakpoint in the alpha change method to see if it's called. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html

Comment: But if I put the breakpoint in the alpha change method when I click "Alpha button" shouldn't the application quit?

Comment: No, just pause, so you can see what it's doing. That's the point of debugging.

Comment: I put the breakpoint and when I press the button "Alpha button" the application quit and Xcode report a green line.

Sorry for my middling english. @Wain

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Inspecting/Inspecting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009975-CH6-SW1

Comment: Ok! Perfect! I understand the error and now the code work correctly. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Thanks :) I was thinking that in any case the code I wrote is really complicated to do something relatively simple. There is another method to do the same thing? In your opinion, applying this code at about 135 view the application could be slow? @Wain

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your sample app is so small that nothing could be assumed from it really. The type of relationship you have would usually be done by delegation...

Comment: My app is simple but the same operation has to run on 150 views on another app. Will the application go fast?

Comment: 150 calls to change alpha? You won't even notice it happen. But why 150 calls between different view controllers? Presumably not all running at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

when you create class1 instance 
    Class1 *class = [[Class1 alloc]init];
class did not link the Livello2Image outlet, Livello2Image is nil.